# Removing .html from URL with .htaccess file does not work

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am trying to remove the .html part from my url. The Problem is, when I click on the Imprint or Privacy Policy, I get a 404 error Page. Why is it like that? Is there something wrong in the HTML or in the .htaccess File? Or do I have to link the .htaccess File into my HTML File?

This is the .htaccess File, I think everything should be fine

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

And this is how I link the file(page) in the code

```
<footer class="site-footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <ul class="footer-links">
              <li>
                <a href="imprint">Imprint</a>
                <a href="privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a> 
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
</div>
</footer>
```

Looking forward to any help :D !

Comment: after saving `htaccess` file did you remove `.html` from all of your files names?

Comment: ohh no didn't do that, but how do I remove it, isn't it a textfile after removing the .html ending?

Comment: Yes but the content inside will make it treatable like an `html` file. You should check this:https://www.geekshosted.com/Blog/how-to-remove-html-from-your-url/#:~:text=html%20showing%20on%20the%20end,to%20come%20across%20more%20professional.&text=In%20order%20to%20save%20the,go%20to%20File%20%3E%20Save%20As.

Comment: this doesn't work at all, i get a 403 error for every page now

Comment: and if i redirect myself to the /index file it just wants to download the index file to my pc